# Hibernate: Select all from one table only instead of 3 joined tables

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I would like to ask if anyone is able to select values from table A only. See the following hibernate code

```
   Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class);
   Criteria t= c.createCriteria("b");
   Criteria k= c.createCriteria("c", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
```

Now it is like selecting values from A, B and C. And it is just too many.

Thank you
Jimmy

Comment: Lets us know about relationship between tables !!

Answer (score 0):

My workaround solution is

1) Create a ProjectionList hibernate variable.

2) identify all columns of table A and put them in the ProjectionList variable.